# How to change the font of the heading number in Microsoft Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, format, styles, microsoft-word-2003

How do you change the font of the heading number?

If I get into the Styles and Formatting tab, then click on the drop down arrow of the heading I want to modify, and then edit the font in the Modify Style window, only the font size of the text changes, but not the number.  Thus, I'd get a large heading number font size with a small heading text font size.  Does anyone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 2003, but a hint is this:

- Right-click on the number to bring up a context menu. In my version of Word, there is a choice "Adjust List Indents" that brings up settings for list indentation and so on.
- Here you can change the font as well.

Hopefully you can even find this now that you know that they named the feature "Adjust List Indents"... :D

Answer (score 0):

Building off what @Mikael said, in Word 2010, you select the text in the header, then right click over it.  In the drop-down menu, select "Font", and you can adjust the font to whatever you need it it be.